# Firebase Android - Change password for other user

Tags: android, firebase, passwords

I have an Admin user account which is able to see all the registered account and their details but I am unable to change other Users password. How do I do that exactly? So far when I do it, I'm only able to change the current logged in User which is the Admin.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking in context of Firebase Authentication, you can only reset the password. This would essentially trigger a password reset email to the owner of the account.

[snapshot from firebase panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edeJE.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try sending an reset email like this.

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().sendPasswordResetEmail("user1@user.com")
.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            Log.d("EMAILTAG", "Email sent.");
        }
    }
});
```

Then when you search for "EMAILTAG" in your android monitor you can see if the email has been sent.

Say you are logged in as "admin@admin.com" and you want to change "user1@user.com" then you just add "user1@user.com" to the parameter.

Comment: Will that send to the current user logged in? Because I want to send it to other users.

Comment: You can send the user you want to update in the parameter "user1@user.com" - I hope this helped, if it did please mark the answer as accepted.